# ‘One of two Japanese winning a medal in this Olympics’

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

I want to write the following sentence:

> He is one of two Japanese winning a medal in this Olympics.

The question is, are 'two' and 'a medal' compatible?

Should 'a medal' be replaced by 'medals'?

Comment: No. Your sentence is grammatically correct. The only plural you need to use is a plural for "Japanese." Unless both of those japanese people won more than one medal each. Here is an example sentence: that fruit is one of two _oranges_ in the basket with a spot on it.

Comment: If you are stating that **EACH** one won a single medal, then leave the last part singular.

Comment: *medal* is fine. However, I would change *winning* to *to win* and *this Olympics* to *these Olympics*.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would not use *Japanese* as a noun. Second, *two* doesn't have to agree with *medal* because it doesn't modify it. You could say "...one of two Japanese athletes to win a medal...". Or you could use the somewhat awful verb form -- "one of two Japanese athletes to medal in this Olympics". Or simply say "He is one of two Japanese medalists in this Olympics".

EDIT

As a commenter says, what you've written isn't incorrect per se, but IMO it's somewhat awkward at first reading and therefore worth rewriting.

Comment: If it were "two Brazilians", would you still have a problem with this?

Comment: @aparente001 good point, but he does bring up the problem that the plural noun of Japanese is Japanese, so that noticing it in the sentence is difficult, leading to the situation/problem where readers think that the term "medal" is the one to be turned into a plural, they will unconsciously and incorrectly recognize Japanese as a singular noun instead of a plural noun.

Comment: @JimMack, I would suggest adding what I said into your answer, or I will make my own.

Comment: @aparente001  No problem. It's the ambiguity that makes it awkward to my eye and ear. Note that I didn't say it was *wrong*, just that I wouldn't do it.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is comfortable with "one Japanese, two Japanese, three Japanese" (as I am), your sentence is understandable as written.

That's not to say you couldn't have some fun rewriting it if you wanted to.

Cf.

> He is one of two Brazilians winning a medal in this Olympics.

Comment: *winning* grates on my ears in this usage. And *Olympics* is plural.